# Autoresize cell after adding subview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am creating a table with custom cells - in the last cell in the table I need to change the `UItextField` for a `UILabel` - which I am doing with this code in `cellForRowAt`:

```
case "Notes":
    if viewing == true {
        for subview in cell.contentView.subviews {
            if subview.description.contains("UITextField") {
                let newField = UILabel()
                 cell.contentView.addSubview(newField)

                 newField.frame = cell.infoField.frame
                 newField.text = profileToShow.notes
                 newField.font = cell.infoField.font
                 newField.addConstraints(cell.infoField.constraints)
                 newField.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

                 for constraint in cell.infoField.constraints {
                     cell.infoField.removeConstraint(constraint)
                 }

                 cell.infoField.isHidden = true
                 newField.numberOfLines = 0
             }
         }
     }
 break
```

I am checking to see if the cell is the correct cell, which it is, adding the label and hiding the UITextField, which all works.  However when I run the program the label is resizing to fit the lines, but the cell is not resizing to fit the label.
What do I need to change to make this cell re-size with the added label, i am using the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` already.

Comment: you can use different cell for textfield and label .

Comment: @KKRocks I know, but this table already has 2 custom cells so I want to try to avoid a third if I can

Comment: and you cant resize cell size until you have not call any reload method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the order in the cellForRowAtIndexPath and add `layoutIfNeeded` after adding constraints

```
case "Notes":
    if viewing == true {
        for subview in cell.contentView.subviews {
            if subview.description.contains("UITextField") {
                let newField = UILabel()
                 cell.contentView.addSubview(newField)

                 newField.frame = cell.infoField.frame
                 newField.numberOfLines = 0
                 newField.font = cell.infoField.font
                 newField.addConstraints(cell.infoField.constraints)
                 newField.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

                 for constraint in cell.infoField.constraints {
                     cell.infoField.removeConstraint(constraint)
                 }

                 cell.infoField.isHidden = true
                 newField.text = profileToShow.notes
                 cell.layoutIfNeeded()
             }
         }
     }
 break
```

Comment: I tried this but it hasn't caused the cell to resize to fit the label

Comment: how are you adding constraints to the textField, from storyboard or programmatically ?\

Comment: from storyboard

Comment: Then could you please try adding the label from storyboard with leading trailing top and bottom space and hide it for rest of the cells and show for the specific cell that you need

Comment: I guess newField.addConstraints(cell.infoField.constraints) this adds height constraint too to the label try as I mentioned above(adding from storyboard)

Comment: I have added a label to the custom cell which is hidden for the other entries and used on this one, but the cell is still not resizing.

Comment: its constraints are going to the superview of the cell

Comment: got it!   In the new label I had forgotten to set the number of lines to 0.   Thanks for the help :)